# Rotation Animation in Blender - Making a plane flap rotate at the angle of the wing

Tags: modeling, animation

Currently working on a jet airplane which has a titled tail fin from which I would like to make the tail rudder come out and rotate to 45 degrees but with the wing angle as the pivot point how do I do it pls.
I will include a copy of the blend file for ease of reference. The file is slightly different cause I improved the design of the flaps.
[image]
Please keep in mind that the same action will have to be mirrored  on the opposite side since the jet had 2 tail fins.
Thanks for all the help you can give me.
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image] Angle of the tail fin from the front.

Comment: 45° in relation to what? Do you know what parenting is? Have you tried it? If it failed, then how did it fail, how does the result differ from what you want to achieve?

Comment: Tried to add a picture to explain better but it is hard. Basically the flap should open from the angled tail wing to act as rdudder.  No I do not know what parting is.

Comment: @ronin074 Just to be clear, MarkusvonBroady said parenting not parting.

Comment: Sorry was a bit in a hurry.  Yes I used parenting quite a bit.  In fact I added main wing flaps parented them to an empty and did the rotation on the empty.  Then I parented the empty to the which and it was ok.  The wing is a flat surface though but this time the tail tip is tilted and I need the flap on it to rotate at the angle as in the pics above.

Comment: Googling for "Blender parenting" gives many resources including videos teaching this technique. I think once you understand it, the problem will become trivial. Unless that's not the entire problem, hence the "need details for clarity" flags.

Comment: I think I just found the solution.  I first parented the flaps to the tail wing.  Then I set the origin point of the flaps to the line  of the flaps nearest to the same line on the tail wing,  The I set the rotation to the face of the flap and rotated.  It is not  a100% perfect rotation but quite close.   I keyframed the start and stop point.  Now all I have to do is copy and paste the keyframes on the time line when I need the rotation to take place.